# How to use an Android device as bluetooth USB dongle?

Tags: nexus-one, bluetooth, usb

Is there a way to use my android device as a bluetooth USB dongle without rooting it?

Comment: what are the functionaries you are looking for?

Comment: Bluetooth forwarding from my Nexus to my notebook.

Comment: If you want to add Bluetooth to your laptop, it's much more effective to just buy a dongle.  Here's a [USB Bluetooth adapter for $2.85 shipped](http://www.amazon.com/Bluetooth-USB-Micro-Adapter-Dongle/dp/B001EBE1LI/ref=pd_sxp_f_pt).

Comment: Thanks for this comment, but this is not what I actually intended to do.

Comment: Bluetooth dongles are 1 on eBay.

Comment: I asked a similiar question, please look:

http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/91645/phone-as-bluetooth-card-for-my-computer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are curious if you can plug your phone into the USB port on your laptop and use the bluetooth connection of your phone as if you had bluetooth service on your laptop.

No, that is not possible.  The USB drivers for your phone do not permit that type of functionality.

Comment: Yes, that is what I wanted to know. Hopefully one of the future Android versions will support this.

Comment: Why is it not possible?  You can tether the wifi and you can tether the GPS?

Answer (score 3):

This is possible or not possible depending on what you want to *do* with the bluetooth.  If it's something that an app on the phone can do, and you are willing to enable USB debugging mode on the phone and put the SDK's adb driver on the netbook, then you can indeed have the PC make requests over usb for software you create for the phone to do things with its bluetooth.

But if you want to do bluetooth things that applications (sdk, native, or poking around behind the scenes unsupported) cannot, then you are out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can, but with remote controller apps that makes your phone control your PC through wifi, therefore giving you access to anything you connect via bluetooth from your smartphone.

Comment: Is there any app you can recommend?