# can i use my android phone as a bluetooth receiver for my pc

Tags: hardware, bluetooth-pairing

is it possible to connect my phone with usb cable to my pc and use the phone as a Bluetooth receiver

Comment: [How to use an Android device as bluetooth USB dongle?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/1198)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I'm pretty sure this isn't possible.

If it is, then it will depend largely on the phone you have and drivers available from the community or manufacturer. It won't be something any Android phone can do, even if it does have Bluetooth, it will depend on a lot of external factors.

Alternatively, USB bluetooth dongles are very small - and inexpensive on Amazon, Newegg, or in most electronics stores and other places.

Comment: @joserodrigo If you're satisfied, don't forget to mark this as the accepted answer (with the tick/check mark on the left), so other users will know your question is answered.