# Use Android device to enable my computer to access Bluetooth devices

Tags: bluetooth

My computer can communicate with my Android due to being on the same WiFi network. I have Bluetooth headphones and perhaps other Bluetooth devices (Bluetooth mouse, etc). I just bought a Bluetooth dongle for my computer. However, given that my Android device can communicate with my computer anyway via WiFi, I wonder if it's necessary?

If anything, if it's possible, will quality deteriorate?

My question is a bit more awesome than [How to use an Android device as bluetooth USB dongle?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1198/how-to-use-an-android-device-as-bluetooth-usb-dongle). This one asks if Computer -> USB -> Android phone -> Bluetooth is possible

I am asking if Computer -> WiFi -> Android phone -> Bluetooth is possible. In fact, I am interested in Computer -> Bluetooth -> Android phone -> Bluetooth too.

Why would I? Well, Windows 10 cannot connect to 5 Bluetooth headsets at once. Maybe sending the sound to my smartphone that can connect to 5 would solve that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use an Android device as bluetooth USB dongle?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1198/how-to-use-an-android-device-as-bluetooth-usb-dongle)

Comment: Maybe it's not *quite* a duplicate, as the other question is specifically about USB, and this one mentions Wi-Fi, so I'll wait for the questioner's opinion.

Comment: That one asked how to use android phone as bluetooth dongle. What I want is something even more awesome. The phone doesn't even have to be connected to the computer.

Answer (score 0):

So, actually making your phone into a Bluetooth dongle is a little bit nasty due to permission issues. *But*, there is another way.

As you are willing to use this "measure" to stream your PC's audio to your Bluetooth headset, you can download an audio streaming app from the Play Store (such as SoundWire for Android), set up the connection between your PC and your smartphone, and *then* you share your phone's media through the phone's Bluetooth service to the headset.

Maybe there can be a loss of synchronization for games and videos, but music will be just fine!